# What's the correct way to take automatic backups of docker volume containers?

Tags: docker, backup

I am in the process of building a simple web application using NodeJS that persists data to a MySQL database and saves images that have been uploaded to it. With my current setup, I have 4 Docker containers - 1 for the NodeJS application, 1 for the MySQL server, 1 Volume Container for the MySQL Data and 1 Volume container for the uploaded files.

What I would like to do is come up with a mechanism where I can periodically take backups of both volume containers automatically without stopping the web application.

Is it possible to do this and if so, what's the best way?

I have looked at the [Docker Documentation on Volume management](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/) that covers backing up and restoring volumes, but I'm not sure that would work while the application is still writing data to the database or saving uploaded files.

Answer (score 0):

To backup your database I suggest to use mysqldump, that is more safer then a simple file copy.

For volume backup you can also run a container, link the volume and tar the contents together.

In both cases you can use additional containers or process injection via docker exec.

Comment: I would have to stop the web application while doing a backup, correct? WHat I'm wondering is if there is a way to do this without stopping the web application